# Вывод даты окончания учебного заведения

Tags: дата, c++

Здравствуйте.

Решал задачу и наткнулся на вот такой непонятный момент.

Условие задачи таково:
Написать программу, по номеру студенческой группы определяющую год выпуска. 
Номер группы вводится в формате А0209 — всегда одна буква (латинская), затем 
4 цифры (номер группы и год поступления). Год необходимо напечатать полностью; 
предусмотрите работу с группами, поступивших в XX и XXI веках.

Далее задача была мною решена таким образом:

```
 int main()

 {

  time_t t;

  time(&t);

int year=localtime(&t)->tm_year-100;
int x;

string  god,grup,god1,god2;
cout<<"Vvedite nazvanie gruppi: ";
cin>>grup;
god1 = grup[3] ;
god2 =  grup[4];
god = god1+god2;
x = atoi(god.c_str());
    if (x>year)
    {
        cout<<19<<x+6;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<20<<x+6;
    }
```

}

Всё работает верно, за исключением годов 00, 01, 02, 03. Когда ввожу эти года, выводит дату окончания учебного заведения трехзначным числом, то есть ввожу 00, соответственно получаю 206, а если ввожу года не из вышеперечисленных, то всё нормально. К примеру, 07-2013, 75- 1981. И так далее. Так что же тут не так? )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> то есть ввожу 00 , соответственно получаю 206

Чтобы напечать `6` как `06` (чтобы получить 2006):

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  int n = 6;
  std::cout << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << n << std::endl;
}
```

Чтобы избежать зависимости программы от текущего времени (cdd15 возвращает 1921 сегодня, а через полгода она будет возвращать 2021), фиксированная эпоха может быть использована, например: 1970, тогда сdd15 всегда соответствует 2021:

```
year = (x >= 70) ? 1900 + x : 2000 + x;
graduation_year = year + 6;
std::cout << graduation_year << std::endl;
```

Заодно это исправляет баг с cdd99 (19105 -- неправильно, 2005 -- правильно).